# Why is my modal not popping up in the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal which is supposed to pop up when I click the button. However, when I click the button; nothing happens:

Heres what I did:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class = "row text-center">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-button" name="submit-button" type="submit" value="Save">
    
     <input class="btn btn-danger" id="reset-button" type="reset" value="Reset">


   <div class="well well-large">
    <div id="form-content" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
      <h3>Add transaction</h3>
     </div>

     <div class="modal-body">
      <form class="transaction" name="transaction">
       <input type="hidden" name="trans_date" value=<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");?>><br>
       
       <label class="label" for="trans_payment_mode">Payment mode</label><br>
       <select class="form-control" name="trans_payment_mode" id="payment_mode" class="required">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="cash">Cash</option>
       </select><br>

       <label class="label" for="trans_amt">Transaction amount</label><br>
       <input type="text" name="trans_amt" class="input-xlarge"><br>

       <label class="label" for="trans_details">Transaction details</label><br>
       <textarea name="trans_details" class="input-xlarge"></textarea>
       
       <input type="hidden" name="trans_cust_id" value=<?php echo $cid;?>><br>
       <input type="hidden" name="trans_admin_person" value=<?php echo $aid;?>><br>
      </form>
     </div>

     <div class="modal-footer">
      <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send" id="submit_trans">
      <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

    <div id="thanks">
     <p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#add-transaction" class="btn btn-primary">Add Transaction</a></p>
    </div>

  </div>
  </body>
```

I have the above modal containing add-transaction which will populate a modal. Please help.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS needs a bit work but you are missing a data_target class in your button. Add a div with an id and another div with the class modal-dialog.

Also change the line

```
<div id="form-content" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
```

to

```
<div id="modal-content">
```

Other code changes

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

...

<p><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#add-transaction" class="btn btn-primary">Add Transaction</a></p>
```

You can see it in the fiddle below

https://jsfiddle.net/4peLpye5/1/

EDIT - There is no php in the JSFiddle

Answer (score 1):

It's a combination of a few issues.

1. No need for the `hide` class on the modal
2. No need for the `display:none` style on the modal
3. Missing `id` of `add-transaction` on the modal